# Emacs highlight-symbol in multiple windows

Tags: search, emacs, window, highlight

Is it possible to highlight symbols in multiple windows?
I'n often using the excellent "Highlight-Symbol" or "Iedit" packages to search and highlight symbols in a source file. Unfortunately this works only in the buffer of the current window. So I'm looking for an easy way to highlight the symbols not only in the current window but also in the other windows (normally I'm working with 3 or 4 source file windows).

I also tried "occur/moccur" or similar but they open always a new window with a list of occurences.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should do the trick.  It takes the original and walks over the window list.  (Curiously enough, `walk-windows` didn't work.)

```
(defun highlight-symbol-at-point-all-windows ()
  "Toggle highlighting of the symbol at point in all windows."
  (interactive)
  (let ((symbol (highlight-symbol-get-symbol)))
    (unless symbol (error "No symbol at point"))
    (save-selected-window                           ; new
      (cl-dolist (x (window-list))                  ; new
        (select-window x)                           ; new
        (if (highlight-symbol-symbol-highlighted-p symbol)
            (highlight-symbol-remove-symbol symbol)
          (highlight-symbol-add-symbol symbol))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try command **`hlt-highlight-symbol`** in library [**Highlight**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/HighlightLibrary) ([`highlight.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/highlight.el)).

It is bound by default to **`C-x X h s`** (by default, commands in the library use prefix key `C-x X`).  With a *prefix arg* (**`C-u`** `C-x X h s`) it acts on all buffers that are visible or iconified.  With no prefix arg it acts on only the current buffer (or on just the *region* if it is active).

You can **unhighlight** using the same key sequence, but with **`u`** instead of **`h`**.  So `C-u C-x X u s` unhighlights the symbol in all (visible or iconified) buffers, and `C-x X u s` unhighlights it only in the current buffer (or active region).

---

(I just added the this prefix-arg behavior today.  If you pull the library from [**MELPA**](http://melpa.milkbox.net/) instead of the above (EmacsWiki) link then you might need to wait up to a day to get the latest version.

Comment: Tried to include that library but got the following error:"Symbol's function definition is void: hlt-remove-if-not". I'm not an Lisp programmer, don't yet know what is missing.

Comment: Please try again. You apparently downloaded just before I moved that function def earlier in the file, to fix that.  Sorry for the trouble.